# Why is this input asking 2 times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone explain why when I run this it asks for input 2 times when I say to create another save file?
I'm  using python 3.9.1 on a mac with default python IDLE.

Here is my code:

```
import pickle
names = []
count = 0
times = 1
a = "false"
gameplayfunc = "false"
while (count < 9):
    for i in range(times):
        names.append(input('Please enter save file name: '))
    x = input("Would you like to create another save file?")
    if x == "Yes" or x == "yes" or x == "YES":
        names[i]
        pickle.dump( x, open( names[i], "wb" ) )
        times = times + 1
        a == "true"
    elif x == "No" or x == "no" or x == "NO":
        namee = names[i] + json
        pickle.dump( x, open( namee, "wb" ) )
        gameplayfunc = "true"
        count = 10
while a == "true":
    count = 10
    count = 1
    a == "false"
    
...

for i in range(times):
    print(names[i])
```

Comment: I see what you're doing with `count=10`, but you really mean to write `break`. It tells python to immediately exit the while loop.

Comment: Note: You can say `if x.lower() == "yes"`

Comment: I did all of that, it did not solve any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pickle
names = []
count = 0
times = 1
a = "false"
gameplayfunc = "false"
while (count < 9):
    for i in range(times):
        names.append(input('Please enter save file name: '))
    x = input("Would you like to create another save file?")
    if x == "Yes" or x == "yes" or x == "YES":
        names[i]
        pickle.dump( x, open( names[i], "wb" ) )
        times = times + 1 # Times is incremented!!!!
        a == "true"
    elif x == "No" or x == "no" or x == "NO":
        namee = names[i] + json
        pickle.dump( x, open( namee, "wb" ) )
        gameplayfunc = "true"
        count = 10
```

Notice in your code, you are asking the user to enter a file name `for i in range(times)`. If the user says "yes", you are incrementing `times`, and thus the first time you ask for the file name, `times` is 2, which is why it asks twice. If you say yes a second time, it will ask for three file names.

Note also that `open`ed files should be closed, you should instead write something like

```
dump_file = open( names[i], "wb" )
pickle.dump( x, dump_file )
dump_file.close()
```

Also note that `True` and `False` exist in python, which allows you to write `if a` instead of `if a == True` if you assign `a = True` and `a = False`.

Comment: I know about the true false thing but it does not seem to be working so I just used strings  ¯\_(ツ)_/

Comment: @rcode Note that `True` and `False` are case sensitive. If my answer answers your question please accept it or please comment the problem with the answer.